# Visually changing how a string of characters is represented in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, alias, ligature

[Prettify symbols](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.prettify-symbols-mode&ssr=false#overview) is an extension in vscode that changes a sequence of characters visually without affecting what the code does. For example, visually changing --> to ⟶ while the coding language uses -->. However, this extension creates seemingly random symbols throughout the file and is no longer maintained. Therefore, that extension is hardly usable at the moment.

Fira Code uses ligatures to do something similar (or the same I am not sure).

What other ways are there to visually change a string of letters ? I am mostly interested in solutions for vscode. As an example I would like to change

~[\Omega]

to

Ω

visually for the user but the code uses the original ~~[\Omega]

[EDIT: I found this github [page](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/Ligaturizer) that adds ligatures to a font. Unfortunately when one creates a ligature where the "hidden" symbol contains many characters and the visible symbol contains a few symbols, a long trace of spaces replacing the missing characters is left behind. The prettify symbols extension mentioned before does not have these spaces. For those that are still interested in making ligatures with the second link, this Fira code [font page](https://beautifulwebtype.com/fira-code/glyphs/?i=5) shows the names of symbols in Fira code. That might be helpful when making a new font from Fira code using the first link of this edit (which is the second link of the question) ]